# SQLSRV Overriding Website Output in IIS 7/PHP 5.4

Tags: php, iis, sqlsrv

I have a simple setup of **IIS 7** with **PHP 5.4**. Everything has been working fine until I needed to add **MS SQL Server** support. I downloaded the SQLSRV package provided through [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), extracted the appropriate DLLs to my PHP `ext` directory and added the extension entry/configuration in `php.ini` like so:

```
; MS SQL Server

extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll

[sqlsrv]
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems=-1
sqlsrv.LogSeverity=-1
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors=0
```

... with an additional change to the `extension_dir` setting:

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

..., and restarted my server. Now, when I run any request, I get:

```
PHP_RINIT for php_sqlsrv: entering
sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors = Off
sqlsrv.LogSeverity = -1
sqlsrv.LogSubsystems = -1
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 10240
PHP_RSHUTDOWN for php_sqlsrv: entering
```

Sometimes, the first line is missing, but it's generally the same problem. No page is generating proper text/HTML anymore! What has happened? Thanks.

Comment: What exact line did you add to php.ini? Will you be using PDO?

Comment: Maybe. Check my edits.

Answer (score 0):

On the balance of probability, I imagine you're using the wrong sqlsrv dll. First things first: did you download SQLSRV from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098)?

I'll assume you want the PDO version (I use it; it works very well!). From the file name, I can't tell what you have, but for your circumstances you should should be using `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll`. As you're using IIS, you'll have an NTS version of PHP, which should be used with non thread safe extensions.

Try replacing the dll you're using with that one, and reload the application pool in IIS. phpinfo() should show sqlsrv as an available PDO driver. Let me know how you get on... :)